# How to change the name of the XmlRootElement in JAXB deppending on the object?

Tags: java, jaxb

I have the following objects

Film

```
@Entity
@Table(name="film")
@XmlRootElement(name = "film")
public class Film implements Serializable {

    @Id
    @Column(name="id")
    private String fbId;

    @Column(name="title")
    private String title;

    @ManyToMany
    @JoinTable(
        name="direction",
        joinColumns={@JoinColumn(name="film", referencedColumnName="id")},
        inverseJoinColumns={@JoinColumn(name="person", referencedColumnName="id")})
    private Collection<Person> directors;

    @OneToMany(cascade={CascadeType.ALL}, mappedBy="film")
    @MapKey(name="character")
    private Map<String, Performance> performances;

    //GETTERS
    @XmlAttribute(name = "fbId")
    public String getFreebaseId() {
        return this.fbId;
    }

    @XmlElementRefs({
        @XmlElementRef(name="director", type=Person.class)
    })
    public Collection<Person> getDirectors() {
        return this.directors;
    }

    @XmlAnyElement(lax=true)
    public Collection<Performance> getPerformances() {
        ArrayList performancesArray = new ArrayList<Performance>();
        for (Map.Entry<String, Performance> entry : this.performances.entrySet()) {
            Performance value = entry.getValue();
            performancesArray.add(value);
        }
        return performancesArray;
    }

}
```

Person

```
@Entity
@Table(name="person")
public class Person implements Serializable {

    @Id
    @Column(name="id")
    private String fbId;

    @Column(name="first_name")
    private String firstName;

    @Column(name="last_name")
    private String lastName;

    @OneToMany(cascade={CascadeType.ALL}, mappedBy="actor")
    @XmlTransient
    private Collection<Performance> performances;

    //GETTERS
    @XmlAttribute(name = "fbId")
    public String getFreebaseId() {
        return this.fbId;
    }

    @XmlElement(name = "firstName")
    public String getFirstName() {
        return this.firstName;
    }

    @XmlElement(name = "lastName")
    public String getLastName() {
        return this.lastName;
    }

    @XmlTransient
    public Collection<Performance> getPerformances() {
        return this.performances;
    }

}
```

Each film has one (or many) directors and performances which are "Persons". I don't need a class for directors but I do for perfomances because they have more info.

Performance

```
@Entity
@Table(name="performance")
@XmlRootElement(name = "performace")
public class Performance implements Serializable {

    @Id
    @ManyToOne(fetch=FetchType.LAZY)
    @JoinColumn(name="film")
    private Film film;

    @Id
    @Column(name="film_character")
    private String character;

    @ManyToOne(fetch=FetchType.LAZY)
    @JoinColumn(name="actor")
    private Person actor;

    //TO STRING
    public String toString() {
        return this.actor.toString() + " - " + this.character;
    }

    //GETTERS
    @XmlTransient
    public Film getFilm() {
        return this.film;
    }

    @XmlElementRefs({
        @XmlElementRef(name = "firstName", type = Person.class),
        @XmlElementRef(name = "lastName", type = Person.class)
    })
    public Person getActor() {
        return this.actor;
    }

    @XmlElement(name = "character")
    public String getCharacter() {
        return this.character;
    }

}
```

When I run this through JAXB I get this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes"?>
<film fbId="1">
    <description>Nice film</description>
    <person fbId="1">
        <firstName>Quentin</firstName>
        <lastName>Tarantino</lastName>
    </person>
    <performace>
        <person fbId="4">
            <firstName>Steve</firstName>
            <lastName>Buscemi</lastName>
        </person>
        <character>Billy</character>
    </performace>
    <performace>
        <person fbId="2">
            <firstName>Jhon</firstName>
            <lastName>Travolta</lastName>
        </person>
        <character>Vincent</character>
    </performace>
    <performace>
        <person fbId="3">
            <firstName>Samuel</firstName>
            <lastName>L Jackson</lastName>
        </person>
        <character>Jules</character>
    </performace>
    <performace>
        <person fbId="1">
            <firstName>Quentin</firstName>
            <lastName>Tarantino</lastName>
        </person>
        <character>Jimmie</character>
    </performace>
    <title>Pulp Fiction</title>
</film>
```

Is there a way to change the name of the "person"? To get something like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes"?>
<film fbId="1">
    <description>Nice film</description>
    <director fbId="1">
        <firstName>Quentin</firstName>
        <lastName>Tarantino</lastName>
    </director>
    <performace fbId="4">
        <firstName>Steve</firstName>
        <lastName>Buscemi</lastName>
        <character>Billy</character>
    </performace>
    <performace fbId="2">
        <firstName>Jhon</firstName>
        <lastName>Travolta</lastName>
        <character>Vincent</character>
    </performace>
    <performace fbId="3">
        <firstName>Samuel</firstName>
        <lastName>L Jackson</lastName>
        <character>Jules</character>
    </performace>
    <performace fbId="1">
        <firstName>Quentin</firstName>
        <lastName>Tarantino</lastName>
        <character>Jimmie</character>
    </performace>
    <title>Pulp Fiction</title>
</film>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Options:

- Make `Director` extends `Person` with its own `@XmlRootElement`
- Use `JAXBElement<? extends Person>` instead of `Person`

The problem is, @XmlElementRef.name does not work for `@XmlRootElement`, read [here](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/5/api/javax/xml/bind/annotation/XmlElementRef.html):

> If type() is JAXBElement.class , then namespace() and name() point to
>   a factory method with XmlElementDecl. The XML element name is the
>   element name from the factory method's XmlElementDecl annotation or if
>   an element from its substitution group (of which it is a head element)
>   has been substituted in the XML document, then the element name is
>   from the XmlElementDecl on the substituted element.
>
> If type() is not JAXBElement.class, then the XML element name is the
>   XML element name statically associated with the type using the
>   annotation XmlRootElement on the type. If the type is not annotated
>   with an XmlElementDecl, then it is an error.
>
> If type() is not JAXBElement.class, then this value must be "".

By the way

```
@XmlElementRefs({
    @XmlElementRef(name = "firstName", type = Person.class),
    @XmlElementRef(name = "lastName", type = Person.class)
})
```

does not seem valid to me. `@XmlElementRef` are not supposed to map properties of the target class.

Comment: Thanks for the "XmlElementRefs" i've already fixed that. I've already fixed the director... thanks